# Changing the fire rate while button pressed

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a 2D shooting game on Unity using C# now and I want to increase the fire rate of the ship for 5 seconds when it gets a power up item. It kinda works but when the ship gets the power up, the fire rate does not change until the button is released and pressed again. Is there a way to change the fire rate as soon as it gets the power up even while the button is being pressed? Also, the power up function is something that I came up with and if there is a better way to make the power up functions, that will be very helpful too. Thanks in advance :)

```
void Update(){
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)){
        InvokeRepeating("Fire", 0.000001f, fireRate);
    }
}
void PowerUp()
{
    Upgrade = true;
    timeLeft = +5f;
    if (Upgrade == true)
    {
        fireRate = 0.1f;
    }
    if (timeLeft <= 0)
    {
        Upgrade = false;
        fireRate = 0.5f;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass an reference type to the `Fire` coroutine instead of a `float` fireRate.

Just wrap `fireRate` in a class should work:

```
class FireData
{
   public float fireRate = 0.1;
}
```

Then in your script,

```
FireData fireData = new FireData { fireRate = 0.5f };
void Update(){
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)){
        InvokeRepeating("Fire", 0.000001f, fireData);
    }
}
void PowerUp()
{
    Upgrade = true;
    timeLeft = +5f;
    if (Upgrade == true)
    {
        fireData.fireRate = 0.1f;
    }
    if (timeLeft <= 0)
    {
        Upgrade = false;
        fireData.fireRate = 0.5f;
    }
}
```

In `Fire()` coroutine, use this `fireData.fireRate` to get the fireRate.

By the way, I think your power up functions is good enough.

But the way of using coroutine is not correct.Don't call `InvokeRepeating` on the same function multiple times.

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)){
    InvokeRepeating("Fire", 0.000001f, fireRate);
}
```

Instead, you should use a bool value to control when the fire will start.

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)){
    fireData.Firing = true;
}
if(fireData.Firing)
{
    InvokeRepeating("Fire", 0.000001f, fireRate);
}
```

Also remember to add a logic to stop firing via [`StopCoroutine`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StopCoroutine.html).

Comment: Sorry, I was busy w/ other stuff that I couldn't make the changes until now. Also took me a while to understand how to use coroutines. 
Appreciate your help and the descriptive explanation!!